# Sum all column values after each import

Tags: excel, vba

My current code reads manhours(integer values) from different workbooks and exports them to a column in a master output sheet. After each import I want to sum the total amount of hours that is exported to the main sheet, however, 
I'm unsure as to how to do so without summing the entire column. Additionally, after summing up the total manhours from each sheet, I want to compare this value with that from the sheet to confirm if I copied all the rows correctly.

My outputsheet looks like this after each import:

```
data----------data----------hours(sheet1)    
data----------data----------hours(sheet1)    
data----------data----------hours(sheet1)    
data----------data----------hours(sheet2)    
data----------data----------hours(sheet2)
```

My current code looks like this:

```
Option Explicit

Sub manhours()
    Dim Files As Variant
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long
    Dim sh As worksheet
    Dim outputsheet As Worksheet
    Dim erow As long
    Dim manhours As Long

    Workbooks.Open Files(i)
    Set sh = Sheets("manhours")

    For j = 2 to 30   
        erow = outputsheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row 'empty row
        If IsEmpty(Cells(j, 3) = False Then
            outputsheet.Cells(erow, 1).Resize(1, 2).Value = sh.Cells(j, 1).Resize(1, 2).Value 'copies the first 2 columns containing other data values
            outputsheet.Cells(erow, 3) = sh.Cells(j, 3) 'column 3 from sh contains manhours
        End If
    Next j

    manhours = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(outputsheet.Columns(3)) 'unsure how to sum only the values from sheet i and not the entire column
    MsgBox (manhours) ' msgbox than gives the total man hours

    manhours = sh.Range("C31") 'total manhours from sheet is in sh.Range("C31")
    'MsgBox (True/False) 'unsure how to do this

    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: You can sum an entire column, right? Blank cells won't affect the total.

Comment: Also, remove the parentheses: `MsgBox manhours`. Then for the check, you can do `MsgBox manhours = sh.Range("31").Value`.

Comment: True, but would you know a way to only sum the values in the column added from the sheet? In the case that I'm summing up the total hours from sheet 2 and there are already hours from sheet 1 in the column.

Comment: Maybe more importantly, you never update `erow` in your loop. So you're continually overwriting the same cells.

Comment: @BigBen you're right. Sorry I copied over the code to stackoverflow and misplaced that line.

Comment: @BigBen also your check works. Thank you very much. My only issue that I need to figure out now is how to only add part of the column.

Comment: Where is `i` loop started? I just see `Next i`. Try [declaring your variables close to where they are used](https://github.com/todar/VBA-Style-Guide#declare-variables-where-used). This would help prevent unused variables by making it easier to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see the need to use `WorksheetFunction.Sum` here.

One option: keep a running sum, like this:

```
manhours = 0 ' reset manhours to 0 for each new file

For j = 2 to 30
    If Not IsEmpty(sh.Cells(j, 3).Value) Then 
        ...
        outputsheet.Cells(erow, 3).Value = sh.Cells(j, 3).Value
        manhours = manhours + sh.Cells(j, 3).Value ' could add an IsNumeric check here to avoid a Type Mismatch
    End If
Next j

MsgBox manhours ' no parentheses
MsgBox manhours = sh.Range("C31").Value
```